# (Java) String color doesn't turn back into white?

Tags: java, string, variables, colors

```
class Main {
  public static final String reset="\u001B[0m";
  public static final String red="\u001B[31m";
  public static final String white="\u001B[37m";
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("A");
    System.out.println(red+"A"+reset);
    System.out.println(white+"A"+reset);
    String b="B";
    System.out.println(b);
    System.out.println(red+b+reset);
    System.out.println(white+b+reset);
    String c="C";
    System.out.println(c);
    c=red+c+reset;
    System.out.println(c);
    c=white+c+reset;
    System.out.println(c); //prints red 
    String d="D";
    System.out.println(d);
    d=red+d;
    System.out.println(d);
    d=white+d;
    System.out.println(d); //prints red
  }
}
```

How do i make Line 17 & 23 print in white again?

More text so i can post this  More text so i can post this  More text so i can post this  More text so i can post this  More text so i can post this  More text so i can post this  More text so i can post this  More text so i can post this  More text so i can post this  More text so i can post this  More text so i can post this  More text so i can post this  More text so i can post this  More text so i can post this  More text so i can post this  More text so i can post this

Comment: For what you need import java.io.*;?

Answer (score 0):

The variables c and d are being modified by concatenating the red and reset escape codes, which changes the color of the text to red.

Comment: how do i make them turn white again?